# Prettier кавычки для ключей объекта, содержащих подчеркивание в имени

Tags: javascript, eslint, prettier

С сервера приходит объект в котором есть ключи, у которых в имени может быть нижнее подчеркивание

например:

```
data = {
  my_array: []
}
```

в проекте используется стиль наименования camelCase. Имена с нижним подчеркиванием **хочу оборачивать в кавычки**. Но Prettier не понимает такого и хочет кавычки убрать.
Пробовал по документации настраивать поле propsQuote - не помогло. Есть ли варианты как-то добиться желаемого?

конфиг Prettier сейчас:

```
module.exports = {
  bracketSpacing: false,
  singleQuote: true,
  trailingComma: 'all',
  tabWidth: 2,
  printWidth: 100,
};
```

[image: пример]

Comment: https://prettier.io/docs/en/next/options.html#quote-props `preserve` не работает?

Comment: Так. видимо я поспешил задать вопрос. preserve решает проблему. Спасибо